# How can I pin custom location to my Facebook feed via API (PHP)?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sorry for my bad English!
I have a problem with Facebook php api. How can I make post in Facebook, with my custom Latitude and Longitude? (pin location)

```
$token = $request->input('facebook_token');
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => env('SOCIAL_FACEBOOK_ID', ''),
        'app_secret' => env('SOCIAL_FACEBOOK_SECRET'),
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
    ]);
    try {
        $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', array(
            'message' => $request->input('text'),
            /*'place' => array(
                'location' => array(
                    'latitude' => $request->input('lat'),
                    'longitude' => $request->input('lng'),
                )
            )*/ // DOESN'T WORK

            /*'latitude' => $request->input('lat'),
            'longitude' => $request->input('lng'),*/ // THIS TOO =(
        ) , $token);
```

"message" field works great, by I can't get how to pin location, I've read [this documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed), but still don't understand.

By the way:

```
$response = $fb->post('/me/feed?message=test message', array(), $token);
```

This also works great.

Comment: `place` needs to be the id of an existing page that represents a location. You can not make a post with custom lat/long coordinates.

Comment: so, i should pin a nearest place?

Comment: You should use the `place` the user is actually at